# How to load SQL data one step at time with recycler view

Tags: php, android, sql, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that display a list of video game. I want to display a lot of video games from a SQL data base. For asking my data base I use a PHP script for getting my list but I loads to much datas and my return list is empty.

I want to load datas one step at time when the user swap to the down the recycler view but I have no idea how can I am supposed to do that.

My Php :

```
$empty = empty($result) ;

if($empty == 1){

    $sql_parti = "SELECT * FROM ccb_game INNER JOIN ccb_console ON ccb_game.game_fk_console = ccb_console.console_id";

    //getting result
    $result_parti = mysqli_query($con,$sql_parti);
    
    //creating a blank array
    $result = array();
    
    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_parti)){
        array_push($result,array("game_id"=>$row['game_id'],
                                 "game_english_name"=>$row['game_english_name'],
                                 "console_id"=>$row['console_id'],
                                 "console_english_name"=>$row['console_english_name']));
    }
    
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

My Java code, I retrieve data and full the RecyclerViewCheatUpdater with its constructor

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_GET_CHEAT_FROM_GAME, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    System.out.println("Response is: "+ response);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArrayResult  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayResult.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = jsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = jo.getString(Config.KEY_CHEAT_ENGLISH_TITLE);
            String description = jo.getString(Config.KEY_CHEAT_ENGLISH_DESCRIPTION);
            Cheat cheat = new Cheat("1",title,description);
            cheats.add(cheat);
    }


    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    RecyclerViewCheatUpdater recyclerViewUpdater = new RecyclerViewCheatUpdater(context,llm,customCheatAdapter,cheats,recyclerView) ;

    activity.runOnUiThread(recyclerViewUpdater);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("That didn't work!");
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(Config.KEY_CHEAT_FK_GAME, id);
                return params;
            }
        };
```